# Simple xml example doesn't work. Any tips please?

Tags: xml

I thought I would try to acquire a bit of xml. I am looking at [this webpage](https://www.sitepoint.com/really-good-introduction-xml/).

I tried first with css, I can handle css OK. It did what it should do.

Then I tried with xml and xsl. The examples below are taken directly from the webpage mentioned above.

This is the xml file letter-text.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
 <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="letter2text1.xsl" version="1.0"?>  
 <letter>  
  <to>Mom</to>  
  <from>Tom</from>  
  <message>Happy Mother's Day</message>  
 </letter>
```

This is the xsl file letter2text1.xsl :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">  
  <xsl:output method="text"/>  
  <xsl:template match="/letter">  
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>  
  </xsl:template>  
  <xsl:template match="to">  
    TO: <xsl:apply-templates/>  
  </xsl:template>  
  <xsl:template match="from">  
    FROM: <xsl:apply-templates/>  
  </xsl:template>  
  <xsl:template match="message">  
    MESSAGE: <xsl:apply-templates/>  
  </xsl:template>  
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

This xsl does nothing. Firefox outputs:

> Mom Tom Happy Mother's Day

Before I proceed, I would like to make the simple examples work.

Can anyone please tell me what needs tweaking??

Comment: The xsl looks OK. How are you testing? The xsl file needs to have the name letter2text.xsl and be on the same folder as the xml file on your web server, e.g. if you are testing from a browser like Chrome

Comment: I'm using Firefox. Everything is in 1 folder at the mo, myxml. I tried the next example, letter-html.xml and letter2html.xls same problem. If I put href="letter2html.xsl" the parser should look in the current directory, I think.

Comment: As per this fiddle here, your [XSL transforms the XML as expected](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPJ9hDW). Many browsers refuse to apply transforms directly from the local file system due to security concerns. You'll either need a web server, or to use code to load the xml and xsl and do the transform.

Comment: Aha, so the code is good? I have a little homework website on GoDaddy, I can try it there. Thanks! Funny though, the previous example was with letter.xml and letter.css, that worked well, and I played around with the css for various effects. The letter2text.xls doesn't do it on my machine!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link and the tip!

Comment: Yes. Since FF 68, XSL is considered to be a security error when used locally, but CSS is not. I don't know why. According to [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1565261), you can make a change in about:config to revert to the earlier behaviour, and I tested it and it does work. But then you are prone to the mentioned security problem of course.

Comment: @MrLister1 probably because XSLT is a lot more powerful than CSS, and can therefore do more damage: for example it can access external resources using the `document()` function.